# Unable to loop trough the links when crawling a website with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to crawl one website but I have a problem with looping trough page.
I want to create a system that collects all links, then click on each link and collects data (date in this case).
I wrote a code but I keep getting this error:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.109)
```

I have tried to increase the sleep interval but the result is the same.
The error happens after on second iteration (after first link).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
import time

# url for crawling
url = "https://bstger.weblaw.ch/?size=n_60_n"
    
# path to selenium
path = 'path to selenium'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)    
    
# click on search button
buttonClickSearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/div/input').click()
time.sleep(3)    
    
# get all links
all_links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li.sui-result div.sui-result__header a')
print(all_links)
print()

# loop trough links and crawl them
for link in all_links:
    
    # click on link
    print(link)
    time.sleep(4)
    click = link.click() # I GET THE ERROR HERE ON SECOND ITERATION
    time.sleep(4)
        
    # get date
    date = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div.filter-data button.wlclight13').text
    day = date.split('.')[0]
    month = date.split('.')[1]
    year = date.split('.')[2]
    date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day
    print(date)
    print()
    
    # click on back button
    back_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a').click()
    time.sleep(4)
    #scroll
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200)")
```

Comment: Post the complete error message, so that we will be able to know which line of code is throwing that exception.

Comment: I get a error in for loop, when I want to click on the second link. Everything is good for first link (i get the data extraction) but when I want to click on the second link I get the error.

Comment: Refer the link - [Regarding the error](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/stale-element-reference-exception-selenium-webdriver/). Need to refine `all_links` inside the for loop. And also the website is so unstable - Clicking on back button does not navigate to previous page properly and other methods to navigate to previous page does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of elements get the `href` value and use `driver.get()` to navigate.

//Get the href value

```
all_links =[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.sui-result >.sui-result__header> a')]
print(all_links) 

for link in all_links:
    
    driver.get(link)
    driver.refresh()
        
    # get date
    date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.filter-data button.wlclight13"))).text
    day = date.split('.')[0]
    month = date.split('.')[1]
    year = date.split('.')[2]
    date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day
    print(date)
```

---

If you want to go ahead with your code you need to re-assigned your element like below.

```
all_links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li.sui-result div.sui-result__header a')
print(all_links)
print()

# loop trough links and crawl them
for link in range(len(all_links)):
   #Re-assined it again
    all_links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li.sui-result div.sui-result__header a')
    # click on link
    print(all_links[link])
    time.sleep(4)
    all_links[link].click() 
    time.sleep(4)
        
    # get date
    date = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div.filter-data button.wlclight13').text
    day = date.split('.')[0]
    month = date.split('.')[1]
    year = date.split('.')[2]
    date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day
    print(date)
    print()
    
    # click on back button
    back_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a').click()
    time.sleep(4)
    #scroll
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200)")
```

---

**Update:**
Navigating url not refreshing the page. added `driver.refresh()` to appear the date.

```
all_links =[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.sui-result >.sui-result__header> a')]
print(all_links) 

for link in all_links:
    
    driver.get(link)
    driver.refresh()
        
    # get date
    date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.filter-data button.wlclight13"))).text
    day = date.split('.')[0]
    month = date.split('.')[1]
    year = date.split('.')[2]
    date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day
    print(date)
```

You need to import below library.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, but I need to do this in one 'window', with sending only one request.
I have managed to apply the same logic that I have tried here to other websites, and it works good. I do not know what is the problem here

Comment: @taga : Try the other answer I have posted and let me know how this goes.

Comment: First example does not work good, it always returns the same date, and second example breaks after third link

Comment: @taga : it seems need to do java scripts enabled however i have added page refreshed option to refreshed the page. Try out updated one.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned clicking on **Back button** is unstable. But can use the **Next button** to navigate to other links.

And better to apply some Explicit waits.

```
driver.get("https://bstger.weblaw.ch/?size=n_60_n")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

buttonClickSearch = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@aria-label='search button']")))
actions.move_to_element(buttonClickSearch).click()

time.sleep(5)
all_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='sui-result__header']/a")
all_links[0].click() # Click on the First link.

for i in range(20):
    ...
    next = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@class,'next')]")))
    next.click() # Click on next link for 20 iterations.
```